# TCP SYN Double on HTTP Access

Tags: tcp, duplicates

while analyzing my network HTTP traffic I found, a single request http:// shows two connection. I used a netfilter module to log TCP sequence. I tried to visit a simple apache's "It Works!" default page.

A single request initiated two connection with sport 35156 and 35157 to dport 80. 
Could any explain why I see two connection for a single request? 
Is it possible to get rid of this?
Is there chance of malware presence?

kern.log

```
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.888978] |SYN
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.888992] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841020 ACK:0
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889045] |SYN
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889052] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889060] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 SEQ:3372377752 ACK:4133841021
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889225] |SYN
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889235] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:376871724 ACK:0
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889258] |SYN
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889264] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889273] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 SEQ:3375376005 ACK:376871725
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889387] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889397] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841021 ACK:3372377753
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889424] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.889432] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:376871725 ACK:3375376006
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.890359] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.890370] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841021 ACK:3372377753
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.890411] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.890420] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 SEQ:3372377753 ACK:4133841473
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.891155] |ACK
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.891193] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 SEQ:3372377753 ACK:4133841473
May  8 17:19:19 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.891351] |ACK
May  8 17:19:23 vmdsk01 kernel: [185735.891360] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841473 ACK:3372377963
May  8 17:19:23 vmdsk01 kernel: [185739.880282] |SYN
May  8 17:19:23 vmdsk01 kernel: [185739.880291] |ACK
May  8 17:19:23 vmdsk01 kernel: [185739.880312] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 SEQ:3375376005 ACK:376871725
May  8 17:19:23 vmdsk01 kernel: [185739.880492] |ACK
May  8 17:19:33 vmdsk01 kernel: [185739.880502] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:376871725 ACK:3375376006
May  8 17:19:33 vmdsk01 kernel: [185749.890397] FIN
May  8 17:19:33 vmdsk01 kernel: [185749.890409] |ACK
May  8 17:19:33 vmdsk01 kernel: [185749.890420] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 SEQ:3375376006 ACK:376871725
May  8 17:19:33 vmdsk01 kernel: [185749.923800] |ACK
May  8 17:19:34 vmdsk01 kernel: [185749.923805] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:376871725 ACK:3375376007
May  8 17:19:34 vmdsk01 kernel: [185750.903428] FIN
May  8 17:19:34 vmdsk01 kernel: [185750.903440] |ACK
May  8 17:19:34 vmdsk01 kernel: [185750.903450] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 SEQ:3372377963 ACK:4133841473
May  8 17:19:34 vmdsk01 kernel: [185750.931508] |ACK
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185750.931519] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841473 ACK:3372377964
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666526] FIN
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666536] |ACK
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666546] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:376871725 ACK:3375376007
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666572] |ACK
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666581] <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 --> eth0:(192.168.2.168):35479 SEQ:3375376007 ACK:376871726
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666725] FIN
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666732] |ACK
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666741] eth0:(192.168.2.168):35478 --> <NULL>:(192.168.2.169):80 SEQ:4133841473 ACK:3372377964
May  8 17:19:35 vmdsk01 kernel: [185751.666757] |ACK
```

Comment: **NOTE:** Sorry I pasted **different instance** of log file which initiates connection with sport `35478` and `35479`.

Comment: If the client is a browser this is not unusual, a user-agent is free to open multiple TCP connections for a single request.  It may do this to pipeline HTTP or it may establish a second connection as a timeout-backup (chrome does this) or for some implementation specific optimisations like predictive pre-connect. This connection may end up never being used at all.  If you capture everything on that interface you will be able to see the HTTP stuff & satisfy yourself what's going on.

Comment: @Alex K: Yeah it seems to be HTTP pipeline. I tried same with WGET utility, only one connection was established.Thanks GOPI